# Cron trigger with Quartz run in every minute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I have a schedule should run in every 5 minutes. Below is my Quartz scheduling source code.

```
 IScheduler sched = container.Resolve<IScheduler>();
        sched.JobFactory = new AutofacJobFactory(container);
        sched.Start();

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<ProcessInvoiceJob>()
               .WithIdentity("InvoiceJob")
               .Build();              

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithCronSchedule("0 0/5 * * * ?")//every 5 minutes
            .Build();

        sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Actually this code works fine with visual studio. I have a logger and it is recorded a log in every 5 minutes. But when I publish and host as a web site in my local IIS server, it is running the schedule in every minutes. Then I changed the cron schedule to every 6 minutes, every 7 minutes etc. In this every time it is running the schedule in every minutes. Please give me a direction for solving the issue....

Technology I'm using

MVC, C#, SQL Server

Comment: what if call sched.Start(); after sched.ScheduleJob(...) ?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the `WithCronSchedule`, I suggest using `WithSimpleSchedule`.

```
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .StartNow()
    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
        .WithIntervalInMinutes(5)
        .RepeatForever())
    .Build();
```